# Virtual host returns 404 when i add file path

Tags: php, html, apache, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

i'm having a problem whit a web-site project i'm developing by myself.
I've downloaded XAMPP to manage the web-site server, db and files, than i configured a virtual host so now when i go to the url [www.woofcms.com](http://www.woofcms.com), it opens the index.html as i wanted.
The problem is that if i add something to the URL (like [www.woofcms.com/login](http://www.woofcms.com/login)) the server responds whit an error 404.
These are the settings of the 'httpd-vhosts.conf' file:[httpd-vhosts.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FV2JE.png)

Can you help me whit this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please paste your code in the question, instead of providing it as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, what i wanted to do was (when apache doesn't find a page) showing the index.html instead of the default apache's 404 error page.
To do so all i needed to do i to add 'ErrorDocument 404 /index.html' in my vhost.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added those pages onto the virtual site yet? There is no reason for the site to automatically have a login page so if there is no login suburl it will of course return an error 404.

Comment: i’m try to create a sort of urlmanagere adn for do that i need to split the main url (putting the url into a variable using php function and then split using an explode) so i need the code to run that part first and the (if i not find a page related to that piece of url) i return 404.

Comment: this project is going to be a web site and i’m practising how manage virtual hosts before buy a domain and a server.